# Error replacing numbers in an array with predefined values in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to replace values in an array (0-99 repeating) with a new set based on the value of n. For eg. if `n=0`, values 0,10,20..90 should be replaced by 0,1,2..9 and the rest should be 10. The following code works okay for all values of n (0-8) except 9. For 9 it gives the message `long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'` I've tried a lot debugging this but can't seem to find what the problem is.

```
import numpy as np
arr1=[[19][29][ 0][11][ 1][86][90][28][23][31][39][96][82][17][71][39][ 8][97]]
n = 9
d = {}
for i, j in zip(range(n, 100, 10), range(10)):
    d[i] = j
arr2 = np.vectorize(d.get)(arr1)
arr2[arr2 == None] = 10
```

`arr1` is the original array and `arr2` is the new array.

output should be

```
arr2=[[ 1] [ 2] [10] [10] [10] [10] [10] [10] [10] [10] [ 3] [10] [10] [10] [10] [ 3] [10] [10]]
```

Comment: @sacul if n=1 values 1,11,21...91 should be replaced with 0,1,2..9 and the rest by 10. I need to create 10 such arrays. The first 0-8 worked fine except 9.

Comment: check `np.putmask`. Can you put a sample of your original array and the output you want?

Comment: @Mstaino original `[[19]
 [29]
 [ 0]
 [11]
 [ 1]
 [86]
 [90]
 [28]
 [23]
 [31]
 [39]
 [96]
 [82]
 [17]
 [71]
 [39]
 [ 8]
 [97]...`  output `[[ 1]
 [ 2]
 [10]
 [10]
 [10]
 [10]
 [10]
 [10]
 [10]
 [10]
 [ 3]
 [10]
 [10]
 [10]
 [10]
 [ 3]
 [10]
 [10]....`

Comment: @NoelDSouza please edit your question to so that it contains a [Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I.e. you need to import numpy, define `arr1`, so that anyone can run your code and reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.putmask` (see here) to replace specific values with a formula based on those values (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html#numpy.putmask)).

As for your case, you can [modulus](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html): it's easier and faster than using a dictionary. Does this represent your desired input/output?

```
import numpy as np
n = 9

arr1=np.random.randint(0, 100, size=20)
arr2 = arr1.copy()
np.putmask(arr2, (arr1-n)%10 == 0, arr1 % 10)

print(arr1)
print(arr2)
```

> [69 70 63 52 27 96  0 40  2 90 36 24 17 90 67 58 74 50 11 58]
>
> [ 9 70 63 52 27 96  0 40  2 90 36 24 17 90 67 58 74 50 11 58]

**Edited for your desired output:**

```
n = 9 
arr1=np.random.randint(0, 100, size=20)
arr2 = arr1.copy()
mask = (arr1-n)%10 == 0
np.putmask(arr2, mask , arr1 // 10)
np.putmask(arr2, ~mask , 10)
print(arr1)
print(arr2)
```

> [28 72 87 31 87  3 34 96 61 14 25 79 74 25 38 87 38  8  6  8]
>   [10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10  7 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10]

If you want to use a dictionary, set the default value in the `.get` method

```
arr2 = np.vectorize(lambda x: d.get(x,10))(arr1)
```

Comment: edited: please put a sample of your array and what you expect of output in your post!

Comment: this works, thank you. any idea why my code gave an error for 9?

Comment: Not sure, but my guess is that when you are creating your array using `np.vectorize`, when the first element yields a number (n=9), numpy interprets the array is an int type it throws an error when the next is None. This does not happen in the other cases as None is the first element (so the numpy knows it is a generic data type). You can bypass this error, if you want to use a dictionary, using the default for d.get (edit in answer)

Answer (score 1):

Correction:

```
arr1=[[19],[29],[ 0],[11],[ 1],[86],[90],[28],[23],[31],[39],[96],[82],[17],[71],[39],[ 8],[97]]
```

`d` is:

```
{9: 0, 19: 1, 29: 2, 39: 3, 49: 4, 59: 5, 69: 6, 79: 7, 89: 8, 99: 9}
```

The error, with **full traceback**, is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack53618793.py", line 8, in <module>
    arr2 = np.vectorize(d.get)(arr1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1972, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2051, in _vectorize_call
    res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

With `n=8` `d` is `{8: 0, 18: 1, 28: 2, 38: 3, 48: 4, 58: 5, 68: 6, 78: 7, 88: 8, 98: 9}`.  `arr2` has a lot of `None` because that's the default for `get`.

`vectorize` performs a test calculation with the first element of `arr1`, and uses the result to set the return `dtype`.

With `n=8`, `get(19)` returns `None`, so the return dtype is set to `object`.

With `n=9`, `get(19)` returns integer `1` (it's in `d`), so the return dtype is `int`.  That produces an error when another `get` returns `None`.

One fix is to set the `otypes`.

```
arr2 = np.vectorize(d.get, otypes=[object])(arr1)
```

Another possibility is to replace `get` with a `get(

```
arr2 = np.vectorize(lambda x: d.get(x,10))(arr1)
```

Then you don't need the `None` replacement step.

This vectorized `get` is probably not the fastest way of doing this replacement.  But if you do use `vectorize` you need to watch out for traps like this automatic `otypes`.

*When you ask about an error, you should include the **full traceback**, or at least enough so we know exactly where the error occurs.  It wasn't obvious to me until I ran the test case.*